# How to exit a program with an exit code: Java

Tags: java

I have an application in Java. I'd like to specify the "exit code" of my console application. How can I apply an exit code for the `registerButton`?

```
final JTextField passwordText = new JTextField(20);
passwordText.setBounds(10, 120, 160, 25);
panel.add(passwordText);

JButton loginButton = new JButton("OK");
loginButton.setBounds(10, 150, 80, 25);
panel.add(loginButton);

JButton registerButton = new JButton("CANCEL");
registerButton.setBounds(180, 150, 80, 25);
panel.add(registerButton);

loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        int i=Integer.parseInt(passwordText.getText());
        if(1<=i &&i<4) {
            JTextField xField1 = new JTextField(5);
            JTextField xField2 = new JTextField(5);
            JTextField xField3 = new JTextField(5);
            JTextField xField4 = new JTextField(5);
```

Comment: Why create `JTextField`s in `actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)`?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you want to terminate with an exit code

```
System.exit(status);
```

Comment: hi, i have add system,exit(0) under panel.add(registerButton). but my java application not showing..

Comment: Not showing what? Is it not showing the exit code when it terminates?

Comment: @Kei Please read what `System.exist()` does, then you will know what happens if you add that line in your "normal" program flow.

Answer (score 2):

you can use System.exit(0)

> public static void exit(int status) Terminates the currently running
>   Java Virtual Machine. The argument serves as a status code; by
>   convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination. This
>   method calls the exit method in class Runtime. This method never
>   returns normally.
>
> The call System.exit(n) is effectively equivalent to the call:
>
> Runtime.getRuntime().exit(n)   Parameters: status - exit status.
>   Throws: SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its
>   checkExit method doesn't allow exit with the specified status. See
>   Also: Runtime.exit(int)

Answer (score 2):

To exit a java program use:

```
System.exit(exit_code);
```

The exit code should be `0` if it is a normal exit and any other number means an abnormal termination.  You can read more information about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System.exit(int StatusCode)`. This will exit your Java program with the specified exit code, eg. `System.exit(0)` will exit your program with status code `0`.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29):

> Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.